# Eclipse JUnit works not properly

Tags: android, eclipse, unit-testing, junit

So i have a an android application project and unit test project to it. I am a beginner in Eclipse and  maybe i don't understand properly how to work with JUnit.

I have written two simple test methods:

```
@Test
public void searchTest() {      
    fail("test is failed");
}

@Test
public void getTest() {     
    assertTrue(10 > 1);
}
```

So my problems are

Firstly: It is obvoius that searchTest must fail but when i run it doesn't happend :

[image]

Secondly: in some reason i can not debug my test methods. I click right button on serachTest in JUnit dialogue and select "Debug" but debugging is not starting.

Thirdly: Only one test method is showing in in JUnit dialogue however i have two methods with @Test annotation in my class. Why does it happend?

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you had selected when you said to Run it as a Test. You need to select the class itself rather than a method within it. The JUnit View will only show you the tests that were run.

And you need to set a Breakpoint in your test code to have any observable difference from just Running the test.

Comment: > You need to select the class itself rather than a method within it



I do so